# Enumerate processes that have loaded a specific DLL

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to get a list of processes that have a specific DLL (d3d9). I'm currently doing it by calling `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` on every process to get the list of its modules and comparing module names with `"d3d9.dll"`. However, this doesn't work on 64-bit processes since `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` fails (my app is 32-bit). Is there any way to achieve this without running a separate 64-bit process just to list modules?

Comment: Quoting MSDN: If the specified process is a 64-bit process and the caller is a 32-bit process, this function fails and the last error code is ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (299).

Comment: You can do it with WMI, CIM_ProcessExecutable class.  Not a load of fun from C++, building the 64-bit version is easier.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to achieve this without running a separate 64-bit process just to list modules?

No there is not, at least not using Win32. You cannot obtain the information you need from inside the WOW64 emulator using Win32 functions. I believe that there are undocumented native API functions that can do what you ask, but I would never recommend such a solution. You are expected to solve this problem with a 64 bit process.